# Persistent data, concurrent access and clear Titan DB

Tags: java, berkeley-db, gremlin, titan

I have different questions about Titan Graph blueprint and gremlin. Actually, i try to implement Titan graph in my java program on Ubuntu but i have different problem. I use titanGraph v0.4.4.

In a first time, you can see my titan configuration in Java program :

```
        BaseConfiguration config = new BaseConfiguration();
        Configuration storage = config.subset(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_NAMESPACE);

        // configuring local backend
        storage.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_BACKEND_KEY, "local");
        storage.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY, "/tmp/testdbtitan");

        // configuring elastic search index
        Configuration index = storage.subset(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_NAMESPACE).subset(INDEX_NAME);
        index.setProperty(INDEX_BACKEND_KEY, "elasticsearch");
        index.setProperty("local-mode", true);
        index.setProperty("client-only", false);
        index.setProperty(STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY, directory + File.separator + INDEX_NAME);

        TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
        graph.createKeyIndex("uuid", Vertex.class);

        return graph;
```

After that, i create a vertex :

```
Vertex r = graph.addVertex(null);
r.setProperty("name", "akrogames");
graph.commit();
```

So, i have one vertex in my Java program but with gremlin i dont see this vertex :

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/testdbtitan') 
gremlin> g.V.count()
==>0
```

i dont understand why i have this problem...

Then, i try to access my database with different instance of my java program but it's not possible because there are a lock in Titan. It's a problem for me because i want to access with different users. help me please...

Finally, i cannot clean my titan DB because i have an exception :

```
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
graph.shutdown();
TitanCleanup.clear(graph);
```

And i have this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Unexpected exception
 during backend operation
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:67)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup.clear(TitanCleanup.java:32)
        at xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.clearDB(XXXXXXX.java:365)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.IOUtils.deleteDirectory(IOUtils.java:24)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.IOUtils.deleteDirectory(IOUtils.java:26)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.IOUtils.deleteFromDirectory(IOUtils.java:17)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.clearStorage(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:169)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.clearStorage(OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.java:59)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.clearStorage(Backend.java:465)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup$1.call(TitanCleanup.java:35)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup$1.call(TitanCleanup.java:32)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:62)
        ... 5 more
```

I have this exception but my DB is cleaned... It's very strange

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/testdbtitan') 
gremlin> g.V.count()
==>0
```

When I open a `TitanGraph` it looks like this:

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan')
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/titan]
```

Not sure if you cut and paste your Gremlin session snippet badly or something, but something is clearly wrong there if `g` doesn't print anything.  That aside, why not open your graph in the Gremlin Console the same way you are doing it in Java by building your `Configuration` object (or using a properties file)?  That seems especially important since you are using ElasticSearch as the shorthand method you are using won't connect to that.

> i try to access my database with different instance of my java program
>   but it's not possible because there are a lock in Titan. It's a
>   problem for me because i want to access with different users.

BerkeleyDB is not designed for this use case.  It is for a single JVM process.  You have two options:

1. Use Rexster which will effectively let you share access to it
2. Use a different backend like Cassandra or Hbase

   I cannot clean my titan DB because i have an exception

Is this error repeatable?  Can it be replicated with a simple Gremlin session? If so please provide such information.  As you can see, it seems to work for me with a basic scenario that doesn't sound too different from what you are doing:

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan044')
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/titan044]
gremlin> g.shutdown()
==>null
gremlin> TitanCleanup.clear(g)
==>null
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan044')
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/titan044]
gremlin> g.addVertex()
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.shutdown()
==>null
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan044')
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/titan044]
gremlin> g.V.count()
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>1
gremlin> g.shutdown()
==>null
gremlin> TitanCleanup.clear(g)
==>null
```

Comment: Hello stephen,

thanks for your response. So, i am sorry i dont have cut and paste gremlin. I have this result :
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/testdbtitan');
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/testdbtitan]
gremlin> g.V.count()
==>2

But with my java program i list all vertex and i have this result :
4
40004
80004
120004
160004
200004
240004

With :
for(Vertex vertex : this.model.query().vertices()) { 
   System.out.println(vertex.getId());
}

Comment: I don't know why it is, but my impression is that there are 2 database... But i have a same directory... When, i just use gremlin, that works perfectly...

Comment: Not sure why that is - I again suggest you convert your config to properties file and use the same file to open the database in both environments.  See if that resolve the problem.  Also, if you don't want problems later, don't use this: `graph.createKeyIndex("uuid", Vertex.class);` to define indices.  Use the Titan native methods: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview

Comment: Ok stephen, after creating a single properties file for my Java program and gremlin environment, it works.

But it's very strange. have you an example with Java configuration for storage and index system ?

For index you use Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Good...glad that cleared up the discrepancy.  There are sample properties files in the `conf` directory of the Titan distribution.  I don't use ES for my usage on a day-to-day basis, but if i did need such a solution I would expect to use ES over other options.

Comment: I also tried to access the titan database with different instance of my java program, even i got Lock exception, and am using Cassandra as my backend storage but still same issue. Is there a way to solve this? where can i get information regarding Titan concurrent writes.